# Why AccessDeniedException is raising when using just created folder?

Tags: java

I'm creating simple object serialization, and creation of **BufferedOutputStream** is raising an exception **AccessDeniedException**. Here is the code:

```
Path filePath = Paths.get("c:\\temp\\");
File xmlFile = new File("c:\\temp\\");
boolean success = xmlFile.mkdirs();
if (!success && ! xmlFile.exists() ) {
    // Directory creation failed
    System.out.println("Failed to create a file: " + filePath);
}

try (
    ObjectOutputStream objectOut = new ObjectOutputStream(
        new BufferedOutputStream(Files.newOutputStream(filePath, StandardOpenOption.WRITE)))){
    // Write three objects to the fi le
    objectOut.writeObject(solarSystem); // Write object

    System.out.println("Serialized: " + solarSystem);
} catch(IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

But directory is empty and if it doesn't not exist, it's created...

Comment: What is `filePath`? I see neither the declaration nor the value? Please note that you should write to a file, not to a directory - just in case `filePath` is actually `"C:\\temp"`. Also note that the name `xmlFile` suggests you have a file, but it point's to a directory.

Comment: And what's `Paths`? What's the actual value of `filePath`?

Comment: Filepath points to С:\Temp, Paths is a class java.nio.file.Paths

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll repeat my comment here: you seem to try to write to a directory not to a file. Try changing `filePath` to a file instead.